# Kinetics of allosteric regulation

Tags: enzymes, enzyme-kinetics

I have found a diagram similar to the following one in my biology textbook. The diagram describes allosteric regulation.

[image]

However, I do not quite understand why the maximum reaction rate $V_{max}$ is still reached, even though I thought this is only possible for a competitive inhibition.

I think that the diagram should look something like this where the maximum reaction rate is not reached.

[image]

Is there simply an error in the diagram or have I misunderstood something here?

Comment: My textbook states clearly that $V_{max}$ remains the same in a case of competitive inhibition but is is lower in case of non-competitive inhibition under which, according to my textbook, you can count allosteric inhibition. Also I see diagrams like [this](http://alevelnotes.com/content_images/i79_Chap9-enzymeinhibition.gif) everywhere where $V_{max}$ is lower for a non-competitive inhibition

Comment: Your text-book is incorrect in saying that allosteric inhibition is not competitive. I do not know what your text book actually says (and do not care). The curves usually show the negative effector not reaching the maximum rate because a very high concentration would be needed to achieve this (and in any case the curves only reach this at infinite concentration). I have added my own answer to the question I cited (as I had been meaning to do for a while because of the confusion these terms cause). Look at my diagram carefully and you will see why allosteric negative effectors are competitive.

Comment: To clarify. The diagram in your textbook is probably correct, if idealized, but I cannot be sure as I presume you have redrawn in it from the spelling mistake "inhibtor".

Comment: Ok, so after watching [this video on Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/biology/energy-and-enzymes/enzyme-regulation/v/noncompetitive-inhibition) and reading your answer to the other question, I got it clear that allosteric inhibition can be competitive. So in the diagram in my textbook I have a competitive allosteric inhibition, right?

Comment: Yes, I have redrawn it, but took caution to have it be exactly the same. I apparently messed up the spelling, though, sorry.

Comment: Easy to make typos in figures. As for your question, I would never use the "term competitive allosteric inhibition" for the reasons I give in my answer. Don't learn terms by rote to parrot back to someone. Think about what is happening and describe it clearly.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, but in general I'm right with saying that allosteric inhibition can be a form of non-competitive inhibition but it does not have to be and could also be a form of competitive inhibition, right?

Comment: So in conclusion, allosteric inhibition can be both competitive and non-competitive. Right?

Comment: Wrong. As far as the other answers to the question go, and in terms of the kinetics and my diagram, I cannot see how there could be a negative allosteric effector that acted in a non-competitive manner.